# Как сделать выборочную / отложенную загрузку js, css и изображений?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, оптимизация-сайтов

Какими способами и инструментами можно оптимизировать загрузку мобильных версий сайта применительно к адаптивному веб-дизайну? Иногда необходимо переделывать фронтэнд без возможности изменений серверной стороны, поэтому ищу лучшее решение с учетом этого момента.

**Ситуация 1.** Есть 2 js и 2 css файла. Как можно сделать, чтобы грузился только js #1 и css #1, в зависимости от screen.width например?

**Ситуация 2.** В dom есть элементы с классом `.only-desktop`, в которых находятся изображения. Какой наиболее быстрый и правильный способ предотвратить загрузку изображений в `.only-desktop`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Здесь](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/overview/select-config) официальное руководство от google, с примерами.

Для начала воспользуйтесь [одним](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) из [готовых](https://github.com/borismus/device.js) [решений](http://headjs.com/), примеры прилагаются. [HeadJs](http://headjs.com/), пожалуй, проще всего.

Сложные правила для [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)  становятся сильно проще, если использовать какой-либо [препроцессор стилей](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/media.html) и [миксины](http://jenius.github.io/rupture/)

Пример для раздельных Javascript с помощью [enquire](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 899px)", {
      match : function() {
        require.ensure(['tablet.js'], function (reqiure) { require('tablet.js')});
      } 
   }).listen();


   enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 900px)", {
       match : function() {
          require.ensure(['desktop.js'], function(require) { require('desktop.js')});
       }
   }).listen();

</script>
```

Этот пример подразумевает, что вы используете require или webpack, поддерживающие сборку догружаемых модулей. Конечно, вы можете использовать любой доступный способ инжекции скриптов и ресурсов.

Тем же способом можно подгрузить enquire, или любую другую из вышеперечисленных библиотек из cdn, не меняя серверную часть.

2. Согласно [этому исследованию](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/), самым эффективным путём запрета загрузки изображений является каскадная перезапись свойства посредством @media queries

Answer (score 8):

Это похоже на какую-то преждевременную оптимизацию. Если у вас действительно такой большой сервис, то тогда проще генерировать макеты под девайсы на серверной стороне, как это делает например apple.

Подгружать css в зависимости от разрешения, можно указав атрибут media
в теге link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      media="screen and (min-width: 601px)" 
      href="device.css">
```

Для JavaScript можно использовать такой хак

```
<script>
if (screen.width < 601) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD").item(0).innerHTML+= '<script type="text/javascript" src="device.js"><\/script>';
}
</script>
```

Вы писали про modernizr.js, посмотрите на [yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com)  с помощью него, вы сможете загружать необходимые вам стили и js файлы в зависимости от условий.

Чтобы изображения не загружались сразу, используйте атрибут fake-src и туда пишите url для фото, потом с помощью JS подставлять url изображения из fake-src в src.

Comment: Спасибо. К сожалению, иногда необходимо переделывать фронтэнд без возможности изменений серверной стороны, поэтому ищу лучшее решение. Добавлю данный момент в вопрос чтобы было понятнее. Поскольку срок окончания конкурсного вопроса через 7 дней, жду еще варианты, возможно будет ещё что-то интересное.

Comment: Ответ выше - действительно набор костылей, как и признался автор. 
Есть нормальные практики,  как разделять код для любых целей. Преждевременной оптимизацией вопрос не является, это наоборот очень распространённый кейс.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете выставить media queries для загрузки файлов в зависимости от разрешения экрана (Ситуация 1) или для загрузки классов внутри файла стилей (Ситуация 2).
Или я не правильно понял ваш вопрос?

Comment: Я ищу лучшее решение условного загрузчика js и css скриптов. Как Modernizr, только ориентированный на работу с адаптивным дизайном. Возможно это библиотека / скрипты / хаки / метод организации кода фронтенда.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, браузер учтёт это в каком-то виде, но всё равно загрузит все стили.

Comment: ниже  со ссылками про готовые решения

Answer (score 0):

добавляейте атрибуты async или defer в зависимости от того что нужно

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.